# WinAPI how to detect in which control took place the copying

Tags: winapi, copy

I wonder how to identify in my win32 application, in  which control the copying occurs.
For example in EditBox, in RichEdit and etc.

In order to figure out whether the copying took place in my app or outside it, I used  the following method:

```
//global variables

HWND hWnd; 
DWORD ProcId; 
HWND nextHandle; 
DWORD currentID;

//then I call two functions on form create

currentID=GetCurrentProcessId();
nextHandle = SetClipboardViewer(Handle); 

//then on  WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message I call 

hWnd = GetClipboardOwner();
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&ProcId);

// functions and checking by IDs whether
// the copying took place in or outside my application 

if(lpdwProcessId==currentID) {...}
```

It works fine, but this is not a solution how to detect in whitch control (in my app) the copying occurs.

Comment: You asked the question, but have been quiet since. Do you still need help?

Comment: On `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`, call `GetFocus` to find out which control has input focus.

Comment: When I press CTRL+C in the RichEdit control, GetFocus() function shows me that it has the focus, but unfortunately GetClipboardOwner() function does not work for it, unlike the Edit control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you could use [`GetClipboardOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649041.aspx). This is not 100% reliable. It's possible for the clipboard to contain data, and for this function to return `NULL`. For a start, the clipboard could have been filled by something other than a control, but I expect there are plenty of ways for the clipboard to be full of data, and have no owner window. But so long as your app doesn't do anything too non-standard with the clipboard, I think it would do the job for you.

If you want to be 100% sure of which control in your app filled the clipboard with data, keep track yourself of the last control to fill the clipboard.

Comment: David, thanks for your comment. After playing around the function GetClipboardOwner() I noticed that while filling clipboard from RichEdit control it returns always zero (NULL), unlike from Edit control.

Comment: In which case you'll just have to keep track of which window filled the clipboard last.

Comment: I can replicate what you describe with rich edit controls. I think you are out of luck. You'll have to keep track.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy to get notified that a rich edit control is being asked to copy to the clipboard. No `WM_COPY` message is sent if you press CTRL+C.

Comment: Thank you David. I have no idea how to solve this problem yet. I have to think about it.